# How to generate core dump file in Linux?

Tags: linux, gcc, gdb

I am trying to generate the core dump file using the below program in Linux.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     char *temp ="ABCDE";
     int i =0;
     temp[3] ='F';
     for (i =0; i <5; i++)
         printf("% Value is %c\n", temp[i]);

     cout<<"Done"<<endl;
     return 0;
}
```

I saved the above source code as sample.cpp and build the file using the below command.

```
     g++ sample.cpp -g -o test
```

Run the output file "test" which produced the error "Segmentation fault". But it didn't generate the core dump file.

```
    ./test
```

I refereed [this](http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/tools/gdb/tutorial.html) . Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The generation of core dump files it is not always enabled. Try with the [ulimit](http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_enable_core.html) command.

Comment: Thanks Raydel Miranda for your help

Answer (score 2):

Some systems are configured not to write core files by default, since the files can be large and rapidly fill up the available disk space on a system. In the GNU Bash shell the command ulimit -c controls the maximum size of core files. If the size limit is zero, no core files are produced. The current size limit can be shown by typing the following command:

$ ulimit -c
0
If the result is zero, as shown above, then it can be increased with the following command to allow core files of any size to be written:(17)

$ ulimit -c unlimited